# SQL number of products bought by at least 5 unique customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have a database with following objects:

- Price (**prodID**, from, price)
- Product (**prodID**, name, quantity)
- PO (**prodID, orderID**, amount)
- Order (**orderID**, date, address, status, trackingNumber, custID, shipID)
- Shipping (**shipID**, company, time, price)
- Customer (**custID**, name)
- Address (**addrID**, custID, address)

I am trying to return the names of products ordered by at least 5 different customers. My code is:

```
SELECT Product.name, COUNT(DISTINCT custId) as cust_count
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN PO
ON PO.prodId = P.prodId
INNER JOIN "Order" O
ON O.orderId = PO.orderId
INNER JOIN Customer C
ON C.custId = O.custId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT custId) > 4;
```

I am getting the following errors:

> The multi-part identifier "Product.name" could not be bound" Ambiguous column name 'custID'

Comment: please use the alias before all column name. Once you have given an `alias` to a table, you must reference the column using `alias` and not the table name

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS When you get a result that you don't expect, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first problem subexpression & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GROUP BY` -- and to use your table aliases:

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(DISTINCT o.custId) as cust_count
FROM Product P INNER JOIN
     PO
     ON PO.prodId = P.prodId INNER JOIN
     "Order" O
     ON O.orderId = PO.orderId
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.custId) > 4;
```

Note that the `JOIN` to `Customer` is not necessary because the id is in the `Order` table.

Answer (score 0):

You also try this.I hope this will solve your problem

SELECT  DISTINCT TOP (5) o.custId, p.name
     FROM Order O INNER JOIN
     PO
     ON PO.orderID = O.orderID INNER JOIN
     Product  P
     ON P.prodID = PO.prodID